# Selenium - Click on an image in Google

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Steps: Go to Google, search Pluralsight, go to images tab, click on first image..

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchField.sendKeys("Pluralsight");
    searchField.submit();
    
    WebElement imagesLink = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Images")).get(0);
    imagesLink.click();
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd']")).click();
```

Is there a better way to find the image?

Comment: Better is fairly subjective so it would be hard to answer that. Please be more specific and then you'll get better answers. Is it too slow? Is it flaky? Are there too many lines of code? Etc. Also be sure to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

simply add `tbm=isch` to directly go to image search

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/imghp?tbm=isch");
WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
searchField.sendKeys("Pluralsight");
searchField.submit();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com/imghp?tbm=isch&q=Pluralsight");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd']")).click();
```

if you mean xpath selector you can try `//a[@tabindex and @style]`

Comment: Thanks. Say I was on the page https://www.pluralsight.com/product/paths - Trying to select the xpath for as an example Java Language Fundamentals...
//*[@class='item-text'] - After finding the class 'item-text' do i search with text() or contains to try to find the particular course?